# Match rows in different dataframes based on multiple criteria without using for-loops

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, left-join, matching

My data contains two different dataframes:

```
visits <- data.frame("visit_nr", "label", "degree", "code")
category <- data.frame("label", "degree", "group", "code1", "code2, "code3")
```

I would like to assign a group to every visit in the dataframe "visits" based on a match in "label", "degree" and "code" between the two dataframes. 
However, a row from a certain "visit_nr" can only be assigned to a specific group if "code2" and "code3" from the dataframe "category" are also listed in the dataframe "visits". Meaning that for a row to be assigned to a certain group, there need to be three rows with the same "visit_nr" where the "label"; "degree" and "code" match with either:

```
- "label", "degree", "code1"
- "label", "degree", "code2"
- "label", "degree", "code3"
```

Because these dataframes both contain over 50 000 rows, I would like to avoid using loops to accomplish this.

Visits

```
visit_nr   | label | degree | code   |  Group
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 354373 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 200200 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 973443 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 475985 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 994320 |   0
```

Category

```
label | degree | group | code1 | code2 | code3
 171  |   1    |   2   | 354373| 200200| 475985 
 171  |   1    |   3   | 354373| 200200| 998282
 171  |   1    |   1   | 354373| 200200| 0
```

**Expected output:**

```
visit_nr   | label | degree | code   |  Group 
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 354373 |   2
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 200200 |   2
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 973443 |   2
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 475985 |   2
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 994320 |   2
```

Comment: Could you clarify your expected output?

Comment: I would like to become a dataframe where the variable group is added to the rows of the first dataframe (i.e. "visits"). If the three codes that are needed to assign a group to a certain visit_nr are all listed within the rows of "visits", all rows with that specific visit_nr can be assigned to that group. If there is no match between the rows in "visits" and those in "category", the variable group should be set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative approach which reshapes `category` from wide to long format, joins with `visits` and counts how many matching codes can be found:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long format
lcat <- melt(setDT(category), measure.vars = patterns("^code"),
     value.name = "code")
# join and count
tmp <- lcat[setDT(visits), on = .(label, degree, code), nomatch = 0L][
  , .N, by = .(visit_nr, label, degree, group)][
    N == 3L]
tmp[]
```

> ```
>      visit_nr label degree group N
> 1: 1601704801   171      1     2 3
> ```

```
# update join
visits[tmp, on = .(visit_nr, label, degree), Group := group, mult = "first"][]
visits[]
```

> ```
>      visit_nr label degree   code Group
> 1: 1601704801   171      1 354373     2
> 2: 1601704801   171      1 200200     2
> 3: 1601704801   171      1 973443     2
> 4: 1601704801   171      1 475985     2
> 5: 1601704801   171      1 994320     2
> ```

#### EDIT

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042285/r-match-rows-in-different-dataframes-based-on-multiple-criteria-without-using-f/52047291?noredirect=1#comment91059862_52047291), the OP has disclosed that

> not all rows in the columns `code2` and `code3` in the dataframe
>   `category` have a value. It also happens that only `code1` has a value
>   different from 0 and `code2` and `code3` have a value of 0. In this
>   case only the first code has to be present within a certain `visit_nr`
>   to assign the matching group to the entire `visit_nr`

So, the simple check if there are exact 3 matching codes does work for the sample dataset but not for OP's production dataset.

I believe the additional requirement can be covered by two modifications:

1. All rows with `code == 0` are removed from `long`
2. If `tmp` contains multiple matches then the one with the highest `N` is picked. If there are ties, `which.max()` picks the first one encountered.

So, the code becomes:

```
library(data.table)
lcat <- melt(setDT(category), measure.vars = patterns("^code"),
             value.name = "code")[code != 0]
tmp <- lcat[setDT(visits), on = .(label, degree, code), nomatch = 0L][
  , .N, by = .(visit_nr, label, degree, group)][
    , .SD[which.max(N)], by = .(visit_nr, label, degree)]
visits[tmp, on = .(visit_nr, label, degree), Group := group]
visits[]
```

> ```
>      visit_nr label degree   code Group
> 1: 1601704801   171      1 354373     2
> 2: 1601704801   171      1 200200     2
> 3: 1601704801   171      1 973443     2
> 4: 1601704801   171      1 475985     2
> 5: 1601704801   171      1 994320     2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)

visits <- fread("
visit_nr   | label | degree | code   |  Group
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 354373 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 200200 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 973443 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 475985 |   0
1601704801 |  171  |    1   | 994320 |   0
")

category <- fread("
label | degree | group | code1 | code2 | code3
 171  |   1    |   2   | 354373| 200200| 475985 
 171  |   1    |   3   | 354373| 200200| 998282
 171  |   1    |   1   | 354373| 200200| 0
")
```

Comment: I tried this approach but got the error: Error in `[.data.table`(lcat, bedragen_1, on = .(bedragen_1$aprdrg, bedragen_1$ernstgraad,  : 
  logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.

Comment: My sample dataset were already `data.table`s. So, I forgot to coerce `visits`. I have modified my code by adding `setDT(visits)`. Please, try again.

Comment: @Sharon I have modified my code to deal with the additional requirements. Please, test it with your production dataset. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Merge` the 2 tables 3 times and then rbind them all like this:

```
df1 <- merge(visits, category, by.x = c("label", "degree", "code"), by.y = c("label", "degree", "code1"), all.x = TRUE)
df2 <- merge(visits, category, by.x = c("label", "degree", "code"), by.y = c("label", "degree", "code2"), all.x = TRUE)
df3 <- merge(visits, category, by.x = c("label", "degree", "code"), by.y = c("label", "degree", "code3"), all.x = TRUE)
#change the column names using names(df) here to maintain consistency
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: Is that what OP asked for ? I feel like df1 should be merged with df2 and df3, rather than binded. With this solution, the exemple visit he gave would be matched with groups 1,2, and 3 wouldn't it ?

Comment: If we merge df1 with df2 and df3, then we will get 3 columns for group whereas I think OP needs only a single column with multiple rows. It would be useful to see the expected output though

Comment: @SmithM,  I think @Sharon needs the first group that occurs. You have it if you extend the solution with `aggregate(df[, c("visit_nr","group")], by = list(df$visit_nr), head)` .

Comment: @Sharon Please, put this in your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: Looks like @Sharon does want multiple rows for each code matching in the visits table